# Run async function from sync function in different thread (Discord.py)

Tags: discord.py, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I have 2 files, each running on different threads currently. One for the main file which runs a flask website, one for a discord bot in a seperate thread. I am trying to call a async method on the discord side to send a message to a user once a request is received.

```
#IN DISCORD FILE (discbot.py)
client = discord.Client()

async def registerSuccess(state, btag):
    ...
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    guilds = client.fetch_guilds()
    async for guild in guilds:
        name = await guild.name
        print(name)
    
#IN FLASK/MAIN FILE (main.py)
@app.route("/oauth", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def oauth():
...
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    #loop.run_until_complete(discbot.registerSuccess(state, btag)) - Did not work
    #asyncio.run(discbot.registerSuccess(state, btag)) - Did not work

# Both of these two above gave me:
#
# "RuntimeError: Task <Task pending coro=#<registerSuccess() running at
# /home/container/arcanabot.py:78> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at
# /usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:157]> got Future
# <Future pending> attached to a different loop"


    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(discbot.registerSuccess(state, btag), loop) - Did not work

#This one never managed to run the function at all
```

I am not very familiar with async functions and asyncio and have had no success with anything above.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, it's not necessary to use Threading while coding in an asynchronous fashion, such as discord.py. We can achieve what you want using [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task).

### What does asyncio.create_task() do?

It submits the coroutine to run "in the background", i.e. concurrently with the current task and all other tasks, switching between them at await points. It returns an awaitable handle called a "task" which you can also use to cancel the execution of the coroutine.

`asyncio.run` won't work because the Discord Client is started using that method. You aren't able to start another function on the loop if there's already another running.

#### How to use create_task

```py
#IN DISCORD FILE (discbot.py)
client = discord.Client()

async def registerSuccess(state, btag):
    await client.wait_until_ready()
   
    async for guild in client.fetch_guilds(limit=None):
        print(guild.name)
    
#IN FLASK/MAIN FILE (main.py)
@app.route("/oauth", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def oauth(...) -> None:
    asyncio.create_task(discbot.registerSuccess(state, btag))
```